# Nerdtree is slowing down neovim in basic config

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree

I am currently trying to create a neovim environment to see if it can be my primary text editor.

But I am already facing a problem with Nerdtree which is making neovim way too slow. I don't understand why this is the case and how to fix it.
My setup is quite basic, I've just followed the basic command lines in https://www.chrisatmachine.com/Neovim/01-vim-plug. Yet after launching nvim on a basic file such as init.vim (at this stage of the configuration, so basically a one-lined text), it takes about seconds to load...
Have you already faced this problem? Do you know what I did wrong or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122960/discussion-on-question-by-paulh-nerdtree-is-slowing-down-neovim-in-basic-config).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Let me copy the relevant info from the deleted comments, in case you cannot get to the chatroom to see them. Link http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/ How are you sure it's NERDtree which is slowing down neovim? Have you checked for errors in `:messages`? Have you read `:h --startuptime` it can be helpful do debug long starting

Comment: the config must be presented as it is (or better simplified as much as possible while the problem persists), before anyone could say anything for sure. (perhaps [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604))